# Upload Attachment to List Item in Sharepoint List Custom Form (PowerApps)

Tags: list, powerapp, attachments, powerapps-forms, patching

We are creating a Sharepoint List Custom Form in PowerApps to collect evidence/attachments supporting a Client.

The Sharepoint List item is created by an Admin. Guest users are given access to their specific List items (via Item-Level Permissions) and they are required to upload attachments to each List Item.

**Sharepoint List - Custom Form (in PowerApps)**

We have created the  Sharepoint Customs Form in PowerApps with a number of Screens and Forms, populated by the Sharepoint List item when opened in Sharepoint:

[image: PowerApp - Attachment Card]

The Attachment displays as 'Unsaved' in the Attachment Data Card, as shown:

[image: PowerApp - Attachment Card - Unsaved]

To 'save' the attachment, I have written some script for the OnSelect action of the Submit button. The code is, below:

```
    Set(TempCol,Patch('Duty Reclaim & Consignments',Defaults('Duty Reclaim & Consignments'),
{
Title: ThisItem.ImporterName & " - " & ThisItem.EPU & " - " & ThisItem.'Entry No' & " - Invoice"
}
));

//Update List Item Attachments & Choices with Patch
Patch('Duty Reclaim & Consignments', LookUp('Duty Reclaim & Consignments',ID=ThisItem.ID),
{
},SharePointForm3.Updates);

//Update Reclaim Status
Patch('Duty Reclaim & Consignments',
    LookUp('Duty Reclaim & Consignments', ID=1),
    {
        ReclaimStatus: {Value: "New"}
    }
)
```

However, the PATCH function I have written is creating a **new** Item in the Sharepoint List. Shown, here:

[image: Sharepoint List - New Item created]

Can someone please help me to ensure that the attachment is updating/editing the Sharepoint List Item that is open in the Custom Form?

Comment: Why are you using `{ }` in 2nd Patch function? Can you try removing it? Let me know if it works.